# Flask Python Buttons not Responding

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a page /contact.html. It has a button which when submitted takes me to a second page (algo.html) with the user logged in. On this second page I have two buttons, but I cannot get either to respond. This is the code I have:

```
@app.route('/contact', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('algo.html')
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['submit'] == 'swipeleft':
        print "yes"
```

On contact.html I have:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post> 
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.name.label }}
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.submit }}
```

And on algo.html I have:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swipeleft" method=post>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swiperight" method=post>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `algo.html` template, you need to submit a form back to the same url `/contact` because that's where you are checking for the value of `swipeleft`:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="post">
   <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swipeleft" />
   <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swiperight" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    return render_template('algo.html')
if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['submit'] == 'swipeleft':
    print "yes"
```

It will always return True for the first if statement and the function will return the rendered template. It will never check the second if statement.

Just switch positions so that it will check for POST request and if the form was submitted.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['submit'] == 'swipeleft':
    print "yes"
if request.method == 'POST':
    return render_template('algo.html')
```

or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['submit'] == 'swipeleft':
         print "yes"

    return render_template('algo.html')
```

Edit: 
You did a serious mistake here:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swipeleft" method=post>
```

change it to:

```
<form method="post" action="URL" > # change URL to your view url.
    <input type="submit" name="swipeleft" value ="swipeleft">
</form>
```

Now in your view, do the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['swipeleft']:
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestions, but it did not work. Is this something to do with the original "submit" button being on contact.html and the swipleft button being on algo.html?

Comment: can you post `algo.html` form where you have the input buttons.

Comment: Do you mean in forms.py? I dont have one, I guess thats why? What do I need to put into it to make it work?

Comment: no no, I meant the html code. `<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "swipeleft" method=post>` just post the form `<form action="url">....<form/>`

Comment: So by URL for your view URL do you mean 'routes.py'?

Comment: No... the url of the function in your view. Like `{{ url_for('contact') }}` or `/contact`

Comment: Ive tried 'contact' and 'algo' in the {{ url_for}} and both give me '400 Bad Request'

Comment: Look it seems you're completely new to Flask. I don't know what you are doing wrong. Change it to '/contact' remove `{{ url_for('contact') }}`. I helped you more than enough, and I gave you enough advices. Just go and read Flask docs again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form.get('submit') == 'swipeleft':
        print "first part"
    elif request.form.get('submit') == 'swiperight':
        print "second part"
    return render_template('algo.html')
```